# Unable to install nodejs and npm on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, npm

I am getting this error:

> Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/packages.microsoft.com_repos_vscode_dists_stable_InRelease - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)

Actually I want to install npm and node in my ubuntu 16.04 system.

I use these steps to install node:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -

sudo apt install nodejs
```

when I perform this:

```
node -v
npm -v
```

it says package is not found.

log after performing `sudo apt install nodejs`

```
sudo apt install nodejs
sudo: unable to resolve host parth-pc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version (4.2.6~dfsg-1ubuntu4.2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apt-clone archdetect-deb dmeventd dmraid fonts-dejavu-extra
  gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-gst-3.0 gir1.2-cogl-1.0
  gir1.2-coglpango-1.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0 gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0
  gir1.2-nma-1.0 gir1.2-timezonemap-1.0 gir1.2-xkl-1.0 junit kpartx
  kpartx-boot libaopalliance-java libapache-pom-java libasm4-java
  libatinject-jsr330-api-java libbsh-java libcdi-api-java libcglib3-java
  libclassworlds-java libcommons-cli-java libcommons-codec-java
  libcommons-httpclient-java libcommons-io-java libcommons-lang-java
  libcommons-lang3-java libcommons-logging-java libcommons-net-java
  libcommons-net2-java libcommons-parent-java libdebian-installer4
  libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libdmraid1.0.0.rc16 libdom4j-java
  libdoxia-core-java libeclipse-aether-java
  libgeronimo-interceptor-3.0-spec-java libgif7 libguava-java libguice-java
  libhamcrest-java libhttpclient-java libhttpcore-java libjaxen-java
  libjaxp1.3-java libjdom1-java libjetty-java libjsch-java libjsoup-java
  libjsr305-java libllvm4.0 liblog4j1.2-java liblvm2app2.2 liblvm2cmd2.02
  libmaven-parent-java libmaven2-core-java libobjenesis-java
  libparted-fs-resize0 libplexus-ant-factory-java libplexus-archiver-java
  libplexus-bsh-factory-java libplexus-cipher-java libplexus-classworlds-java
  libplexus-classworlds2-java libplexus-cli-java
  libplexus-component-annotations-java libplexus-component-metadata-java
  libplexus-container-default-java libplexus-container-default1.5-java
  libplexus-containers-java libplexus-containers1.5-java
  libplexus-interactivity-api-java libplexus-interpolation-java
  libplexus-io-java libplexus-sec-dispatcher-java libplexus-utils-java
  libplexus-utils2-java libqdox2-java libreadline5 libreoffice-gtk
  libreoffice-style-galaxy libservlet2.5-java libservlet3.1-java
  libsisu-inject-java libsisu-plexus-java libslf4j-java libwagon-java
  libxalan2-java libxbean-java libxerces2-java libxml-commons-external-java
  libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java libxom-java libxpp2-java libxpp3-java
  linux-oem-headers-4.13.0-1028 lvm2 python3-icu python3-pam rdate
  snapd-login-service
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
```

Comment: It may not be what you are looking for, but have you tried using [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) ?

Comment: I did but actually I had to do nvm use <VERSION> every time after pc restarts

Comment: That's weird. Maybe this is a permission problem. As a reminder you don't need to run the nvm commands as root (in fact you shouldn't)

Comment: I'm not getting you. actually I've never used sudo while running nvm commands